# Mapping MVC to template using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Teaching myself Spring 5, SpringBoot, and MVC using thymeleaf.  It's a simple application.  I am working with my controller first to get the view populating correctly before I move to the data access layer.

My issue is the view is not populating with the data that I have created in the Controller.

**This is my Controller:**

```
// generates a logger class for you
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/select")
public class AreaCodeController {

/*
 * This method is called BEFORE the @GetMapping method.
 * Building a list of items to display on the select template
 */

@ModelAttribute()
public void addAreaToModel(Model model) {
    // id, code, country, abbr, provStateLongName, StateCode
    List<Area> listing = Arrays.asList(new Area(1000, 123, "US", "AL", "Alabama", StateCode.AL),
            new Area(1001, 124, "US", "MS", "Mississippi", StateCode.MS),
            new Area(1002, 125, "US", "WA", "Washington", StateCode.WA),
            new Area(1003, 126, "US", "WV", "West Virgina", StateCode.WV),
            new Area(1004, 127, "US", "GA", "Georgia", StateCode.GA),
            new Area(1005, 128, "US", "IL", "Illonis", StateCode.IL),
            new Area(1006, 129, "US", "OR", "Oregon", StateCode.OR),
            new Area(1007, 121, "US", "CA", "California", StateCode.CA),
            new Area(1008, 122, "US", "NV", "Nevada", StateCode.NV),
            new Area(1009, 120, "US", "NM", "New Mexico", StateCode.NM),
            new Area(1010, 130, "US", "LA", "WildWilly", StateCode.LA));

    StateCode[] stateCodes = Area.StateCode.values();
    for (StateCode stateCode : stateCodes) {
        model.addAttribute("areaCodeList", filterByStateCode(listing, stateCode));

    }

}

@GetMapping
public String showSelectForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("select", new BusinessNumber());
    return "select";
}

private List<Area> filterByStateCode(List<Area> listing, StateCode sc) 
{
    return listing.stream().filter(x -> x.getCode().equals(sc)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

}
```

**This is my view:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Virtual Business Number Listing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" />

</head>

<body>
 <h1>List of Available Business Numbers</h1>
 <img th:src="@{/images/phone.png}"  style="width:200px;height:125px"/>

 <form method="POST" th:object="${select}">
 
  <div class="grid">
   <div class="area-group" id="abbrs">
    <h3>Choose Your Business Number:</h3>
    <div th:each="area : ${areaCodeList}">
     <input  type="checkbox" name="areaCodeList"  th:value="{area.id}" /> 
      <span th:text="${area.code}">Area Code</span><br/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <input type="Submit" id="submitButton" th:value="Save">
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the behavior I am seeing:**

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 1):

After walking through the code I have solved my own error.   As painful as it was, it involved several things:

- The filterByStateCode method was using the wrong attribute to filter on.  It
  was always returning empty.
- Adding the the same key for the model attribute was overwriting each entry once the filter method was fixed.
- The 'select' template was not keying on the create field.

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your form tag does not know which action to take from the controller so you need to add it this way :

1- in your view : `<form method="POST" th:object="${select}" *th:action="@{/something}"*>`

2-in your controller : above your method @GetMapping should be @PostMapping(**value="/something"**) cause of your form has a post method creating a new object select